# how to return a zero in sql instead of no row selected using case when

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

If I query a output that doesn't exist then I will get nothing returned. i'm looking for default  (0) is returned in that scenario

```
select sum(case when a2.status='SUCCESS' THEN A2.a else 0 end) as success,
sum(case when a2.status='FAILED' THEN A2.a else 0 end) as failed,
sum(case when a2.status='ERROR' THEN A2.a else 0 end) as error
from
(select a.stauts,count(1) a 
from table1 a,table2 b
where a.id=b.id
a.date=sysdate
group by a.status)a2;
```

Note: There is no records for sysdate. I required default value "0" should be return for status.

Answer (score 2):

This query should always return one row, even if nothing matches:

```
select sum(case when a.status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end) as success,
       sum(case when a.status = 'FAILED' then 1 else 0 end) as failed,
       sum(case when a.status = 'ERROR' then 1 else 0 end) as error
from table1 a join
        table2 b
        on a.id = b.id
where a.date = trunc(sysdate);
```

Note that I changed the `where` logic.  `sysdate` (despite its name) has a time component.  If `date` has a time component, you may want:

```
where a.date >= trunc(sysdate) and a.date < trunc(sysdate + 1)
```

EDIT:

If the filter condition matches no rows, then you will get `0` using:

```
select count(case when a.status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 end) as success,
       count(case when a.status = 'FAILED' then 1 end) as failed,
       count(case when a.status = 'ERROR' then 1 end) as error
from table1 a join
        table2 b
        on a.id = b.id
where a.date = trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be count( case when ) and not sum()?

Comment: You should also add NVL or COALESCE over the sums, to deal with the case where the query returns no rows

Comment: @AlexZen: A query with aggregates and without a `group by` will always return exactly one row. That row will contain statistics over the entire result set, even if it's the empty set.

Comment: @Andomar that's true, but if the result set is empty, it will return a single row with NULLs as values. Hence you put NVL or COALESCE, to achieve what OP asked (default value "0")

Comment: select NVL(sum(case when a.status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end), 0) as success,

Comment: @AlexZen: Interesting, I thought `sum` would return `0` for an empty set, but it returns `null` instead. However `count` does return `0`, so you could `count(case when status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 end)`

Comment: @AlexZen.. **Thanks**.. select NVL(sum(case when a.status = 'SUCCESS' then 1 else 0 end), 0) as success .. **Working** **perfectly** :)

Comment: @senthil : Please do take a look at my answer before you use it.

Comment: @AlexZen . . . This query *always* returns one row.  @KaushikNayak . . . `sum()` is correct.

Comment: @AlexZen . . . Ironically, I realized after commenting what you really meant.  I edited the answer, but didn't remove the comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate missing values:

```
WITH cte AS (
     select a.status,count(1) a 
     from table1 a                  --JOIN syntax
     join table2 b
       on a.id=b.id
     WHERE a.date=sysdate           -- are you sure you want precision with time?
     group by a.status
), placeholder AS (
     SELECT *
     FROM cte
     UNION ALL
     SELECT *
     FROM (SELECT 'SUCCESS' AS status, 0 AS a FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'ERROR',   0 FROM dual UNION ALL
           SELECT 'FAILED',  0 FROM dual)  p
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cte WHERE cte.status = p.status)
)
SELECT 
  sum(case when status='SUCCESS' THEN a else 0 end) as success,
  sum(case when status='FAILED' THEN a else 0 end) as failed,
  sum(case when status='ERROR' THEN a else 0 end) as error
FROM placeholder;
```

Answer (score 0):

The only suggestion which comes to mind would be to use a left join in your subquery and move the entire `WHERE` logic to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN a2.status = 'SUCCESS' THEN A2.a ELSE 0 END) AS success,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a2.status = 'FAILED'  THEN A2.a ELSE 0 END) AS failed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN a2.status = 'ERROR'   THEN A2.a ELSE 0 END) AS error
FROM
(
    SELECT a.status, COUNT(1) a 
    FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b
        ON a.id = b.id AND
           a.date = SYSDATE
    GROUP BY a.status
) a2;
```

Your current query is using archaic join syntax which makes it hard to see what is actually happening.  In particular, it makes it hard to see whether or not you might be discarding information during the join which you wish to retain.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `COUNT()`, you don't need `NVL()` or `COALESCE()` to handle `NULL`s ,unlike the case for `SUM()`. `COUNT()` will always return a row with **value=0** when the argument is `NULL` or when no rows are matched.`GROUP BY` too wouldn't be required.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN a.status = 'SUCCESS' THEN 1 END) AS success,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a.status = 'FAILED'  THEN 1 END) AS failed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a.status = 'ERROR'   THEN 1 END) AS error
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.date = TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

If you just want to be clear, test these  queries and pay attention to the result.

```
select SUM(1)    FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0; --NULL
select SUM(NULL) FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0; --NULL
select SUM(NULL) FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1; --NULL
select COUNT(1)  FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0;  -- 0
select COUNT(NULL) FROM DUAL WHERE 1=0; -- 0 
select COUNT(NULL) FROM DUAL WHERE 1=1; -- 0
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e0ee9e/592)

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation without GROUP BY *always* returns a row, so your existing query will return NULLs.

To change a NULL to zero simply apply COALESCE:

```
select
   coalesce(sum(case when a2.status='SUCCESS' THEN A2.a end), 0) as success,
   coalesce(sum(case when a2.status='FAILED'  THEN A2.a end), 0) as failed,
   coalesce(sum(case when a2.status='ERROR'   THEN A2.a end), 0) as error
from
 (
   select a.status,count(1) a 
   from table1 a join table2 b
     on a.id=b.id
   where a.date=sysdate
   group by a.status
 ) a2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to ensure there is always a result even for a query that wouldn't find any row to return, I would do a left join on dual table (for oracle):

```
select q.*  FROM DUAL d LEFT JOIN ( your_query )q on 1=1
```

This way you will always get back a row, no matter what!